# Automapper maps from 2 tables to viewmodel

Tags: c#, automapper

I am a newbie in C# and MVC.

Some background:
The UI screen will call my controller to return a list of 'Meeting Resolutions' which is joined by 2 underlying tables. I created a view model 'MyNewViewModel' and the controller will return it back to UI. UI screen should be able to read & write to the 2 tables.

Automapper is created to map 2 underlying tables to this view model. However, I am faced with issues when using this automapper. Any ideas? Thanks!

My automapper is configured as below:

```
public static void MapToMeetingResolution(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)  
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Table1, MyNewViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionNo, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionNo))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionCd, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionCd))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionDesc, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionDesc))
            cfg.CreateMap<MyNewViewModel, Table1>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionNo, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionNo))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionCd, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionCd))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ResolutionDesc, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ResolutionDesc))

            cfg.CreateMap<Table2, MyNewViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ElectionGroupId, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ElectionGroupId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CorpActionId, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.CorpActionId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Election, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Election))

            cfg.CreateMap<MyNewViewModel, Table2>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ElectionGroupId, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.ElectionGroupId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CorpActionId, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.CorpActionId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Election, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.Election))
        }
```

Now, to use the mapper:

```
public async Task<MyNewViewModel> queryResolutionDetailsById(int id, string username)
{
var result1 = _context.Table1.Where(p => p.CorpActionId == id);
var result2 = _context.Table2.Where(p => p.CorpActionId == id && p.ElectedBy == username);
MyNewViewModel viewmodel1 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MyNewViewModel>(result1);
viewmodel1 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MyNewViewModel>(result2);
return viewmodel1;
}
```

The code throws error at 'AutoMapper.Mapper.Map' step. 
    AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

However, if I changed result1 and result2 to below, error will be gone. But this is not what I wanted.

```
var result1 = _context.Table1.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CorpActionId == id);
var result2 = _context.Table2.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CorpActionId == id && p.ElectedBy == username);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to map a collection to a single item. When you changed the LINQ query from `Where` to `FirstOrDefault`, you ended up mapping a single item to a single object and hence it worked. You should be writing it as follows to make it work

```
    public async Task<MyNewViewModel> queryResolutionDetailsById(int id, string username)
   {
     var result1 = _context.Table1.Where(p => p.CorpActionId == id);
     var result2 = _context.Table2.Where(p => p.CorpActionId == id && p.ElectedBy == username);
     IEnumerable<MyNewViewModel> viewmodel1 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyNewViewModel>>(result1);
     // Even though syntactically correct, this line will overwrite
     // the values from the line above
     viewmodel1 = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyNewViewModel>>(result2);
     return viewmodel1;
   }
```

However, there is a bug in the logic above. The second assignment will overwrite the values from the first mapping assignment. So after the first mapping, you will have to loop through the results of the second collection and map object individually and assign them to related item (you cannot iterate over them sequentially because records returned from two queries won't necessarily match).

Moreover, your AutoMapper mapping profile is too complex because you don't need to specify mapping where source and destination properties have the same name. It can be written in a much simpler manner as

```
public static void MapToMeetingResolution(IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg)  
{
   cfg.CreateMap<Table1, MyNewViewModel>()
      .ReverseMap();

  cfg.CreateMap<Table2, MyNewViewModel>()
     .ReverseMap();                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider  **ResultDTO** (mixture of properties in Table1, Table 2 or more)

In Auto-mapper profile configuration

```
CreateMap<Table1, ResultDTO>().ReverseMap(); 
CreateMap<Table2, ResultDTO>().ReverseMap();
```

auto-mapping combining

```
 var resultDTO = new ResultDTO();
 resultDTO = Mapper.Map<Table1,ResultDTO>(_context.Table1.First());
 resultDTO = Mapper.Map<Table2,ResultDTO>(_context.Table2.First(),resultDTO);   // NOTE: PASS INITIALLY FILLED OBJECT (OTHER WISE IT WILL CONSIDERS NEW OBJECT AND IT SETS DEFAULT VALUES FOR REST OF ITS PROPERTIES)
```